# How to select rows that have column values that are duplicates in one column but different values in the other?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Basically I want to select the rums that appear more than once but with its teachers (namn) having different telephone values (tel) ( thatd be rooms altair, kompis, and mulitplan). How do I select the rows so that it becomes;

```
rum   namn    tel
Altair    Jonas   1074
Altair    Lisen   1076
Kompis    Johan   1067
Kompis    Dina    1076
Multiplan Rikard  1064
Multiplan Henrik  1067
```

From the display below?;

```
tel         namn        rum
----------  ----------  ----------
1083        Agneta      ADRS
1076        Lisen       Altair
1074        Jonas       Altair
1075        Maria       Bus
1032        Amir        Cache
1063        Kjell       Gopher
1077        Kalle       Hub
1077        Magnus      Hub
1077        Urban       Hub
1054        Faramarz    Java
1076        Dina        Kompis
1067        Johan       Kompis
1071        Juha        Modem
1067        Henrik      Multiplan
1064        Rikard      Multiplan
1173        Aida        Pacman
1042        Fredrik     Printer
1076        William     RAM
1080        Janne       Sinclair
1065        Lennart     Telnet
1061        Marie       Thinktank
1073        Alan        VisiCalc
```

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT(), case.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: im using sqlite3

Comment: sorry i need specifics like im hardstuck on this thing.

Comment: What do you mean with _having different telephone values_, for a namn or a rum? (1076 and 1077 have different namn and rum.)

Comment: like hub shouldnt appear in the final table because the teachers that share that room have same telephone number. I want to only show rooms with teachers who have different tel numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `rum` group, compare the count of records having the same `rum` against the distinct count of telephone numbers:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT rum
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY rum
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT tel) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.rum = t2.rum;
```

The acceptance criteria is that a `rum` group has two or more records, while at the same time there are at least two different phone numbers for that group.

### Demo

Comment: sorry, where does t2 come from? I dont get that part. Like I want my bottom table to look like the above table.

Comment: `t2` is just a table _alias_.  It basically labels the `GROUP BY` subquery so that it can be referenced later.  You should try my code and then let me know if it works for you.

Comment: somehow this method works but not the one below by gmb. I appriciate the input from both, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists` to filter the table for records where another record exists with the same `rum` and a different `tel`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.rum = t.rum and t1.tel <> t.tel
)
order by rum, tel
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d537d34c953f4f91eb337e746354d74)**:

```
 tel | namn   | rum      
---: | :----- | :--------
1074 | Jonas  | Altair   
1076 | Lisen  | Altair   
1067 | Johan  | Kompis   
1076 | Dina   | Kompis   
1064 | Rikard | Multiplan
1067 | Henrik | Multiplan
```

Comment: I borrowed your demo, busy on another question, thanks +1

Comment: so my table is called p, so i tried to swap out all the t's with p, but then i get an error on the t1 because table t1 doesnt exist, so.... idk

Comment: @Zerenity: just replace each occurence of `mytable` with the name of your table, and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
select x.*
into #df
from
 (
select 1083 tel, 'Agneta' namn, 'ADRS' rum UNION ALL 
select 1076 tel, 'Lisen' namn, 'Altair' rum UNION ALL 
select 1074 tel, 'Jonas' namn, 'Altair' rum UNION ALL 
select 1075 tel, 'Maria' namn, 'Bus' rum UNION ALL 
select 1032 tel, 'Amir' namn, 'Cache' rum UNION ALL 
select 1063 tel, 'Kjell' namn, 'Gopher' rum UNION ALL 
select 1077 tel, 'Kalle' namn, 'Hub' rum UNION ALL 
select 1077 tel, 'Magnus' namn, 'Hub' rum UNION ALL 
select 1077 tel, 'Urban' namn, 'Hub' rum UNION ALL 
select 1054 tel, 'Faramarz' namn, 'Java' rum UNION ALL 
select 1076 tel, 'Dina' namn, 'Kompis' rum UNION ALL 
select 1067 tel, 'Johan' namn, 'Kompis' rum UNION ALL 
select 1071 tel, 'Juha' namn, 'Modem' rum UNION ALL 
select 1067 tel, 'Henrik' namn, 'Multiplan' rum UNION ALL 
select 1064 tel, 'Rikard' namn, 'Multiplan' rum UNION ALL 
select 1173 tel, 'Aida' namn, 'Pacman' rum UNION ALL 
select 1042 tel, 'Fredrik' namn, 'Printer' rum UNION ALL 
select 1076 tel, 'William' namn, 'RAM' rum UNION ALL 
select 1080 tel, 'Janne' namn, 'Sinclair' rum UNION ALL 
select 1065 tel, 'Lennart' namn, 'Telnet' rum UNION ALL 
select 1061 tel, 'Marie' namn, 'Thinktank' rum UNION ALL 
select 1073 tel, 'Alan' namn, 'VisiCalc' rum
) x;

select rum, namn, tel 
from #df
where rum in  
    (
    select rum 
    from #df
    group by rum
    having count(distinct tel)>1 -- (number of different tel numbers for specific rum)>1
    )
```

[image]